# Convert an image to a URL

Tags: image, url, host, discord.js

## **Hello!**

### Here's the problem:

I am currently making a *Discord Bot*, and I want to make a command that renders a text into an image. I have no problem making this, but the issue is that *Discord.js only accepts URLs, not image objects*. I've been trying to find packages or ways to host images, but I can't find any solution.

#### **Any useful information is appreciated! Thanks :)**

Answer (score 2):

Encode the image to base64,then use the URL:

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,<encoded data>
```

Comment: Do you have the whole code?
For example: embed.setImage('Base64 code');

Comment: I don't think so